# How do I display the full method signature in a class diagram in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, class-diagram

My class diagram just shows the method names but I'd like to see the full signature.  How is this done in VS Professional 2015? I don't see it in the context menu...
[image: screenshot of context menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to to show the full signature. I guess this option is left out because
signatures can be very long, which would result in large class boxes in the diagram.

There is a way to see full signature, but there is a price to pay. Right Click on one of the
methods and select "Properties". This will open properties window where you can see
the method signature. The problem with this is that if you dock "Properties" window on
the right side, you will reduce the space for text editor. Also, in case of long signatures,
you will either have to increase size of "Properties" window or hover cursor over signature
to see it in complete form. You can dock this window down (in a list with "Output",
"Error List", ...) or to the left (with "Solution Explorer", "Class View", ...) but this depends
on personal preference. Some people find this unacceptable.

Comment: Thanks.  The properties actually didn't show the method signature though.  The best view I have is by choosing "Class Details"

Comment: You're welcome! But, I really don't understand how "Properties" window does not show method signature. Don't get me wrong, but did you right click on a method or on a class? When I right click on a method, properties window is displayed with four sections. One of the sections is "Misc", which contains property "Method Signature". I am using VS2015 Enterprise, but there really shouldn't be any difference.

Comment: My mistake.  It's there.  But now I prefer the view in the class details that also gives the comments summary of each parameter :)

Answer (score 15):

Right-click on the class in Solution Explorer and select "View Class Diagram". Once the class diagram opens right-click **outside** of it (in the whitespace) for a different context menu. Select "Change Members Format" and then "Display Full Signature". Right-click on the class diagram and select "Adjust Shapes Width". The full method signatures are shown.

Answer (score 12):

In your class diagram *.cd file right-click in any open space and select
Change Member Format -> Display Full Signature.

[image: Display Full Signature Image]